# Changing struct variables in methods C++

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

so I'm making a C++ Checkers like game for my AI class. I've run into a bit of a hiccup that's driving me insane, each opponent piece is a struct that contains a direction: bool left; bool right; When I try and change one of the values to be true, it doesn't seem to change. It seems to be a scope issue but i don't know why, I've followed it through using vs debug tool. Here's some of the code:

```
     typedef struct {
        int pos;
        int num;
        bool left;
        bool right;
    }opp;
    int scoreOp(opp o){

        if (scoreMoveOp(o.pos + 7) == 10){
            o.left = true;
            return 10;
        }
        else if (scoreMoveOp(o.pos + 9) == 10){
            o.right = true;

            return 10;
        }

    int scoreOp(opp o){

        if (scoreMoveOp(o.pos + 7) == 10){ //scoreMoveOp essentially returns ten.
            o.left = true;
            return 10;
        }
        else if (scoreMoveOp(o.pos + 9) == 10){
            o.right = true;

            return 10;
        }
```

and is all is called:

```
    void checkOPPListForX(){
        for (int i = 0; i < O1Moves.size(); i++){
            if (X == O1Moves[i].second){
                //cout << "O1 has it, and its score is: " << scoreOp(O1) << endl;
                O1Score = scoreOp(O1);
                O1Check = true;
            }
            else O1Check = false;
        }

    checkOPPListForX();
            if (O1Score > O2Score && O1Score > O3Score && O1Score > O4Score){
                //move O1;
                //O1.pos
                if (O1.left)
                    O1.pos = O1.pos + 7;
                else if (O1.right)
                    O1.pos = O1.pos + 9;
            }
```

Comment: You're probably working on copies, where you actually (wrongly) expect to access unique instances.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the variable to the `scoreOp` function *by value*, which means that the function gets a copy. And modifying a copy will of course not modify the original.

You need to pass the argument *by reference* instead:

```
int scoreOp(opp& o){ ... }
//             ^
//             |
// Note ampersand here, which means that the argument is passed by reference
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put your function inside the struct :

```
typedef struct {
    int pos;
    int num;
    bool left;
    bool right;
    int scoreOp() {.....}
}opp;
```

and then  you can call it with opp.ScoreOp()

This solution is if you're not too comfortable passing by reference